# Google-People API Enabled, still says invalid credentials

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-people-api

I have a paid developer account with Google. I have verified my People API is enabled and that I am using the correct API Key and Client ID. When I try the Google Login Start, I get this error in the console for reason.result.error...

```
{
    code: 401,
    message: "The request does not have valid authentication credentials.",
    status: "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
```

I verified that the API key and ClientID are correct. I start off with a method like this for the login button...

```
didClickGoogleLogin = () => {
    // 1. Load the JavaScript client library.
    gapi.load('client', this.googleLoginStart);
}
```

Then it calls the googleLoginStart method...

```
googleLoginStart = () => {
    
    // 2. Initialize the JavaScript client library.
    gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': <API KEY HERE>,
        // clientId and scope are optional if auth is not required.
        'clientId': <CLIENT ID HERE>,
        'scope': 'profile',
    }).then(function() {
        // 3. Initialize and make the API request.
        return gapi.client.request({
        'path': 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=metadata,names,emailAddresses',
        })
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.result);
        const googleID = response.result.metadata.sources[0].id;
        const googleEmail = response.result.emailAddresses[0].value;
        this.updateUser(googleID, googleEmail);
    }, function(reason) {
        console.log("reason: ", reason);
    });
}
```

This was working for me in another web app I wrote a few months ago, but it's not working there now either.

Any ideas why I'm getting an invalid creds error when the API is enabled, the API Key & Client ID are correct?

Comment: Hi there @jtylerm! To prevent a misconfiguration, could you please test the [Try this API!](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/batchGet) menu of the affected method? Also please check the requested scope in the code. In addition to that, please remove the credentials token and force a new synchronization. Please test these approaches and write back sharing your findings.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron The link you provided doesn't have gapi.client.init anywhere so I can't use it to test that method. I tried creating a new project in the Google Developer Console for the People API, got a new API Key, a new Client ID and Secret and those don't help either.

Comment: On the right side you can see the Try this API! menu, where you can test your request/response. Please test it and confirm if they work. This approach would discard problems in the request itself.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron Even there, I don't see anything about gapi.client.init. groupFields, maxMembers, resourceNames, etc don't seem to help. I don't see anywhere that I can specifically choose gapi.client.init and give it my API key and Client ID. Even when I expand that right side window and look at the JS tab, it is all gapi.auth stuff which isn't what I'm looking for. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: With Try this API! you can replicate the API behaviour without manually adding the OAuth 2.0 credentials (they are automatically added). This is useful for seeing if the issue lies on the API side of the implementation side. To better accommodate your simulation, could you please confirm what Peoples API method do you want to use? Please confirm too what is your final goal with this approach.